# i am getting permgen size error in jenkins how to increase

Tags: jenkins

i am getting these below errror while running build using jenkins. can anyone have idea aboout this
Error: Exception in thread "channel reader thread: channel" java.lang.outofmemoryerror:*permgenspace*
And how to increase permgen space in jenkins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should detail your error report.

Anyways its kind of out of memory problem. Try the steps described [here](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/I%27m+getting+OutOfMemoryError).

I am going on a wild guess, In `Manage Jenkins`>`Configure System`. There is an option called,  `Global MAVEN_OPTS` Under `Maven Project Configuration` section. In there try setting

`MaxPermSize=the_size_you_need`

eg: `MaxPermSize=128m`